# Sonata Admin + User Bundle + FOS UserBundle : override login form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm using Sonata admin, Sonata user, and FOS Bundle.
I manage to override the UserAdmin entity to show the fields I need when showing / editing a user, but I'd need to override login form.

Basically, I need the user to login with a username, and a combination of both a password and a PIN code.
I followed this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html and tried with the registration form as in the example, but no matter what I do, I still have the same original fields.

My Kernel file uses this :

```
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
new Application\FOS\UserBundle\ApplicationFOSUserBundle(),
new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
new UserBundle\UserBundle(), //my custom bundle where I define my entity, my UserAdmin...
```

My custom form, which does not implement getParent() to use my own fields, as specified in the doc:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('pinCode');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

The service is declared

```
<service id="coupons_user.registration.form.type" class="UserBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType">
        <tag name="form.type" alias="app_user_registration" />
        <argument>%fos_user.model.user.class%</argument>
</service>
```

The form is declared in FOS config :

```
registration:
        form:
            type: app_user_registration
```

But whatever I try, no changes... I know I'm doing something wrong.. but where ?
Will it be the same process for the login form ? How can I override this form to display my fields ? And then, what would be the best way to override controllers to have it check that the triplet username/password/PIN is correct ?